# How to set my application to full screen mode?

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to set my application to a full screen mode, but still want to be able to drag the collapsed menu from the top (the one that you drag when you receive notification, and you can activate Bluetooth, WI-FI, GPS from it)..

I've tried to set:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

For each activity, but with this - I can't drag and show the top menu.

The device I'm using is Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your activity class. Paste this before ***setContentView(R.layout.main)*** method

```
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```